# Change version of .net core in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-core, azure-api-apps

i have an asp.net core app who works correctly on my computer but not on azure app service:

In one of my api, i return a dynamic type.
from the api runed on my computer i got (with .net core version : 1.0.1):
`{"id":2,"color":"#3da1e8   ","logo":"","name":"...","companySecurities":[]}`

from the api runed on azure app service i got (with .net core version :  1.1.0-preview1-001100-00):
`{"id":2,"color":"#3da1e8   ","logo":"","name":"...","companySecurities":[]`

You can see the the last bracket disapear on azure app service.

I want to know if there is a way to change the .net core version of azure app service to 1.0.1 .

Comment: If you run portable app, you are bound to the installed version(s). You have to create a self-sustained app. It increases the deployment size (all framework libraries are shipped with the app)

Comment: hi @Tseng,  i have created a self-sustained app, when i deploy to azure i got this error : `Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.` It seems to be caused by EF core, because if i remove the services.AddEntityFramework()AddDb... it is working.

Comment: About [unable to load DLL 'sni.dll'] ,please have a try to add `"runtimes": {
"win7-x64": {}
}` in the project.json file.